# Present/remove UIViewController from CCScene?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am presenting in a ccscene an adressBook with  :

```
picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
     picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector]presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

it works good.

When i want to go back to the previous scene, and dismiss it, i do :

```
  [[CCDirector sharedDirector] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:0.1f scene:[Home scene]]];
```

It do goes away, and i do see my scene for 0.3 sec, and it than disappear and i have a black screen (with some message: cant remove child by tag- and i dont remove any child on the next scene, just load background )

So, how would i dismiss it and go back safely to the next scene ?

thanks a lot .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dismissing the modal view , it takes time, so if i load the next scene and the operation didnt finished yet , it takes out also the next scene .

What one have to do is to wait till its done than load the next view : (using blocks)

```
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^
{
   [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:0.4f scene:[Home scene]]];


}];
```

Than when the block is done , it loads the next scene and every thing is working perfect !
I havnt found any other way yet , but i would be happy to know about one .